# Problems with python round() method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an issue with a python decimal list

let said i have a list like the following:

```
>>> a=[2,3.45,7,8,8.75,9]
```

here , I obtain almost the same thing

```
>>> b=[round(x,2) for x in a]
>>> b
[2.0, 3.45, 7.0, 8.0, 8.75, 9.0] # same result
```

when I try something like this:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> b=[round(decimal.Decimal(x),50) for x in a]
>>> b
[2.0, 3.45, 7.0, 8.0, 8.75, 9.0] # same result
```

now when I try to rounded at decimal 0 I obtain this

```
>>> b=[round(x) for x in a]
>>> b
[2.0, 3.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0] # here 8.75 has been rounded to 9.0 , that fine
```

my concern is the second number `3.45` of the list, how to use python `round()` method 
    or any other method to round the decimal part to 50 like 3.50 or in other word
    for each number with decimal part different of 0 and less than 50 round it to 50.

Comment: no times, no subtraction no addition , only round()

Comment: so do you want to round `3.45` to `3`, `4` or `3.5` that is unclear in your question.

Comment: @thefourtheye where 3.29 coming from, i don't understand

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
>>> import math
>>> b = [math.ceil(x*2)/2 for x in a]
>>> b
[2.0, 3.5, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0]
```

Similar to what @Bogdan has said.

Comment: That's great! =) You can help me by accepting my answer also (clicking the check sign on the left) =D

Answer (score 0):

If you want a decimal digit then simply specify it:

```
>>> round(3.45, 1)
3.5
```

Comment: OP wants to round `3.3` to `3.5` also

Comment: @justhalf The OP *never* mentioned `3.3`. If he wanted that then he should edit his question to clarify what he wants.

Comment: It's kind of "hidden" in the obscure last part of the question: "for each number with decimal part different of 0 and less than 50 round it to 50." which is supposed to mean "round 0 < x < 0.5 to 0.5"

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to round to the desired number of decimal places.

```
def round_decimal(dec, places=2):
    return int((dec * 10**places) + 0.5) / 10.**places
```